# object ErrorEvent thrown

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, observable

I'm testing if service getTokenRequest fails.
Then I want to test these 2 lines `this.ngLoggerDispatcher(JSON.stringify(error));
return throwError('get token request');`

In the test `getTokenRequest should throw an error`, I put a spy on `httpService.getAccessToken` and I throw an error `get token request`
Then I call `utilsService.getTokenRequest` and I check if  `utilsService.ngLoggerDispatcher` have been called.

This test run success but the test `getFile`fail with the error `object ErrorEvent thrown`and I don't understand why.

In the browser console I have the error `Uncaught get token request`

utils.service.spec.ts

```
it('getTokenRequest should throw an error', inject([UtilsService, HttpService],
    (utilsService: UtilsService, httpService: HttpService) => {

      spyOn(httpService, 'getAccessToken').and.returnValue(throwError('get token request'));
      utilsService.getTokenRequest('test.pdf', 'hashcode').pipe(
        tap(() => expect(spyOn(utilsService, 'ngLoggerDispatcher')).toHaveBeenCalled())
      ).subscribe();

    }));



it('getFile', inject([UtilsService, HttpService],
    (utilsService: UtilsService, httpService: HttpService) => {

      store.dispatch(new SetUrlDownload('urlDownloadTest'));
      utilsService.getFile().pipe(
        tap(() => expect(spyOn(httpService, 'getFile')).toHaveBeenCalledWith('urlDownloadTest'))
      ).subscribe();

    }));
```

utils.service.ts

```
getTokenRequest(fileName: string, hashcode: string): Observable<TokenRequestResponse> {

    return this.httpService.getAccessToken()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((accessToken: string) =>
          this.httpService.getTokenRequest(fileName, hashcode, accessToken)
        ),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
          this.ngLoggerDispatcher(JSON.stringify(error));
          return throwError('get file');
        })
      );
  }
```

http.service.ts

```
  getAccessToken(): Observable<string> {
    return from(this.tokenService.token).pipe(
      map(({ accessToken }) => accessToken)
    );
  }

  getTokenRequest(fileName: string, hashcode: string, accessToken: string): Observable<TokenRequestResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post<TokenRequestResponse>('...');
  }
}
```

EDIT : Doing command `ng test --source-map=false`
I get  the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` I don't know if it's help
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVoEE.png)

Comment: Can you run your test with the following command - `ng test --source-map=false` and see if you get a detailed error in the browser console?

Comment: I get  the error ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)``` I don't know if it's help